# jq replace value with map and select over a list based on two conditions

Tags: dictionary, select, replace, jq

I am trying to replace the value "data-omitted" inside **services** "check-api" with "xxxxxx" inside plugin "oauth2" in the following json file:

```
{
  "consumers": [
    {
      "username": "api-user2"
    },
    {
      "username": "oauth2-devops-app"
    }
  ],
  "services": [
    {
      "name": "check-api",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "config": {
            "allow": [
              "acl-devops"
            ],
            "deny": null,
            "hide_groups_header": false
          },
          "name": "acl"
        },
        {
          "config": {
            "credentials": false,
            "preflight_continue": false
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "cors"
        },
        {
          "config": {
            "provision_key": "data-omitted",
            "token_expiration": 300
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "oauth2"
        }
      ],
      "port": 5000,
      "write_timeout": 60000
    },
    {
      "name": "check-api2",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "config": {
            "deny": null,
            "hide_groups_header": false
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "acl"
        },
        {
          "config": {
            "credentials": false,
            "preflight_continue": false
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "oauth2"
        }
      ],
      "port": 5000,
      "write_timeout": 60000
    }
  ]
}
```

the jq sentence that i am trying and is the most close to my goal is with the following:

```
cat file.json | jq '.services |= map_values(select(.name == "check-api" and .plugins[].name == "oauth2").plugins[].config.provision_key |= "xxxxxx")'
```

but the result is inserted in all the plugins's names for that service:

```
{
  "consumers": [
    {
      "username": "api-user2"
    },
    {
      "username": "oauth2-devops-app"
    }
  ],
  "services": [
    {
      "name": "check-api",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "config": {
            "allow": [
              "acl-devops"
            ],
            "deny": null,
            "hide_groups_header": false,
            "provision_key": "xxxxxx"
          },
          "name": "acl"
        },
        {
          "config": {
            "credentials": false,
            "preflight_continue": false,
            "provision_key": "xxxxxx"
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "cors"
        },
        {
          "config": {
            "provision_key": "xxxxxx",
            "token_expiration": 300
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "oauth2"
        }
      ],
      "port": 5000,
      "write_timeout": 60000
    },
    {
      "name": "check-api2",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "config": {
            "deny": null,
            "hide_groups_header": false
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "acl"
        },
        {
          "config": {
            "credentials": false,
            "preflight_continue": false
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "oauth2"
        }
      ],
      "port": 5000,
      "write_timeout": 60000
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i select two conditions but based on a list of elements?
Any comment is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `select` filters on the left-hand side of the assignment:

```bash
( .services[]
  | select(.name == "check-api").plugins[]
  | select(.name == "oauth2").config.provision_key
) = "xxxxxx"
```

```json
{
  "consumers": [
    {
      "username": "api-user2"
    },
    {
      "username": "oauth2-devops-app"
    }
  ],
  "services": [
    {
      "name": "check-api",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "config": {
            "allow": [
              "acl-devops"
            ],
            "deny": null,
            "hide_groups_header": false
          },
          "name": "acl"
        },
        {
          "config": {
            "credentials": false,
            "preflight_continue": false
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "cors"
        },
        {
          "config": {
            "provision_key": "xxxxxx",
            "token_expiration": 300
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "oauth2"
        }
      ],
      "port": 5000,
      "write_timeout": 60000
    },
    {
      "name": "check-api2",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "config": {
            "deny": null,
            "hide_groups_header": false
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "acl"
        },
        {
          "config": {
            "credentials": false,
            "preflight_continue": false
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "oauth2"
        }
      ],
      "port": 5000,
      "write_timeout": 60000
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/GkgTcuw7NxN)

Comment: thanks a lot. I thought the only way was using map command. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I like [@pmf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77319580/1409374) better, but here's another way to do it.

```jq
.services
|= map(if .name=="check-api"
       then .plugins |= map(if .name=="oauth2"
                            then .config.provision_key="xxxxxx"
                            end)
       end)
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/Yd_A7HWLbAT).

Answer (score 0):

The minimal change solution to what you already had is this ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BIUx1VhVhlX)):

```
.services |= map_values( 
    select(.name == "check-api" ).plugins[] 
    |= (select(.name == "oauth2" ).config.provision_key |= "xxxxxx")
)
```

And the same without `map_values` ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/3W0CTvvPUyF)):

```
.services[] |= ( select(.name == "check-api" ).plugins[]
            |= ( select(.name == "oauth2" ).config.provision_key |= "xxxxxx" ))
```

---

The issue with your approach is that you are filtering the `service` elements and not the `plugin` elements.

Your selection criteria shown below asks if each `service` element has a `name` matching `check-api` and has **at least one plugin element** with a `name` matching `oauth2`. In the case of the sample input, the second condition is essentially redundant as both `service` elements satisfy it.

```
select(.name == "check-api" and .plugins[].name == "oauth2")
```

evals to:

```
select(true and [false, false, true][]). #true
select(false and [false, true][]) #false
```

Once, you picked the service element, you are then essentially picking **all** the plugins under that service when you do: `.plugins[].config.provision_key`.

In the presented solution, essentially, we make it so that once the plugins are selected, then we iterate through each of the plugins the same way you did for services, and then pick the corresponding `provision_key` of those elements to change.